# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't let me to override font weight for GNOME shell theme

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell, 20.04, customization

I'm creating a GNOME shell theme for Ubuntu 20.04 and GNOME Shell 3.36. I use this:

```
stage, #panel, StLabel {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

none of those can change the font weight.

To test that I'm addressing it right, I used `color: red` and it can change the color of labels in panel. Seems they indicate to the elements correctly.

Why the font weight does not change?

System Font Settings:
[image: Font Settings]

Also Font weight does not change when I select bold in font settings (as it shouldn't change).